# A linking word that expresses contrast but in a positive context

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, phrase-requests

Is there a linking word that expresses contrast but in a positive way in this sentence, I have thought of ( Fortunately) but am looking for something more formal

This fact raises questions as to how to approach rape in other universities, where incidents have been ever publicized. [......] a crime like rape, is manifested within its social context through peoples' attitudes and behaviors. Accordingly, even if there are no publicized incidents or statistics, some signs  can be identified, in any given campus where rape is of prominent occurrence

Comment: One small light in the darkness is that, _as rape is manifested within its social context through peoples' attitudes and behaviors_, even if there are no publicized incidents or statistics, some signs of its occurring can usually be identified ... (Isn't the as-clause in italics rather platitudinous?)

Answer (score 4):

The placement of "*fortunate*" directly prior to the phrase "*a crime like rape*" would be unfortunate, indeed. Instead, open your second sentence with the conjunction "Because" and relocate "*fortunate*", as in the example below.

> This fact raises questions as to how to approach rape in other universities, where incidents have never been publicized. ***Because*** a crime like rape is manifested within its social context through peoples' attitudes and behaviors, even if there are no publicized incidents or statistics, some signs can, ***fortunately***, be identified in any given campus where rape is a prominent occurrence

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you stick to "fortunately".  There's nothing informal about the word and it has a positive meaning.

"**Fortunately**, there is growing awareness of how a rape case must be treated to prevent the victim from suffering additional consequences inflicted by people's attitudes and behaviors."

I'd also suggest "hopefully" or "providentially" but I think "fortunately" fits best.

**Edited the whole sentence to make sure that, contrary to what one of the answerers affirms, I never ever meant to give a positive connotation to rape.**

Comment: It is actually a **misfortune** that a crime like rape has to be, and is, manifested thro people's attitudes and behaviours. Downvote. Misogyny or at least, being oblivious to the plight of women, has no bounds.

Comment: @BlessedGeek  Had I suggested "unfortunately" you would certainly have downvoted it too, as the question asks for a word with a positive meaning.

Comment: The question is about a word, not an opinion.

Comment: You are telling a woman who asked the question, to write in her campus newspaper, to say "**Fortunately**, rape is manifested thro attitude and behaviours." ? Without advising her, of the inherent pitfall in using such a construct?

Comment: @BlessedGeek No, I'm telling the person (man or woman, I don't know) that "fortunately" is an adverb with a positive meaning and that there is nothing informal about it.  That"s all I'm telling her. Don't misunderstand me.

Comment: You are not a robotic answering machine and should take the context of the subject matter into consideration and suggest a more appropriate answer. That is what an advanced English language "expert" should be capable of.

Answer (score 2):

"This fact raises questions as to how to approach rape in other universities, where incidents have been never publicized. Fortunately, even if there are no publicized incidents or statistics, some signs can be identified, in any given campus where rape is of prominent occurrence, because a crime like rape is manifested within its social context through peoples' attitudes and behaviors."

Now we have "fortunately" clearly associated with what is indeed fortunate for the answering of the questions referred to in the first sentence, and not unfortunately appearing to be associated with a terrible crime.

Answer (score 1):

As +Centaurus has suggested, if you really wished to put a positive spin on rape, you would write,

> Fortunately, a crime like rape is manifested within its social context through people's attitudes and behaviors.

But in writing that, be prepared to be thrown heaps of rotten eggs and tomatoes, because there is no fortunateness in being raped, or the manifestation about the tendencies of being raped.

One of the most used phrases for contrasting with a positive or neutral supplementing action is *on the other hand*, often shortened informally to *OTOH*.

> On the other hand, a crime like rape is manifested within its social context through people's attitudes and behaviors.

Other suggestions,

- Distinctively, a crime like rape is manifested within its social context through people's attitudes and behaviors.
- Obviously, a crime like rape is manifested within its social context through people's attitudes and behaviors.
- Normally/usually, a crime like rape is manifested within its social context through people's attitudes and behaviors.
- Perceptively, a crime like rape is manifested within its social context through people's attitudes and behaviors.
- Evidently, a crime like rape is manifested within its social context through people's attitudes and behaviors.
- Evidently, a crime like rape is manifested distinctively within its social context through people's attitudes and behaviors.
- Without doubt, a crime like rape is manifested distinctively within its social context through people's attitudes and behaviors.
- Undoubtedly, a crime like rape is manifested distinctively within its social context through people's attitudes and behaviors.